# Groovy - Jenkins pipeline -

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
>
> Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod {class_namespace}.{class_name} get{variableName}
>     at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectStaticMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:189)

The code looks something like this - with a static variable declaration

```
class DummyClass
{
  static final String variableName='anysortavalue'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- This script was running with the Groovy Sandbox
- Despite this, it appears that a shortcut is being used - disallowing the declaration of all static variables.
- Fix: change the declaration to instance variable:

```
class DummyClass
{
  final String variableName='anysortavalue'
}
```

further reading : https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/